# Full-rank Hadamard product given a certain structure

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, hadamard-product

Let us assume that we have a full-rank randomly chosen $k\times (m\cdot l)$ matrix, $\boldsymbol{H}$, with 
$l \leq k \leq (m\cdot l)$ and no specific structure (e.g., a realization of an IID complex Gaussian random matrix), and a full-rank $(m-r)\times m$ matrix, $\boldsymbol{X}$, which has at least one non-zero element per column and its last $(m-r)$ columns conform a non-singular matrix. Let us also assume that
\begin{equation}
k\cdot (m-r)\geq m\cdot l.
\end{equation}
 We have noticed that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{rank}\left( (\boldsymbol{X}^H\boldsymbol{X} \otimes \boldsymbol{1}_{l\times l}) \odot \boldsymbol{H}^H\boldsymbol{H} \right) = m\cdot l.
\end{equation}
is in general fulfilled (we have tested for $\boldsymbol{X}$ being realizations of an IID complex Gaussian random matrix). Here $(.)^H$ denotes conjugate transpose, $\otimes$ denotes Kronecker product, $\boldsymbol{1}_{l\times l}$ is the $l\times l$ all-ones matrix, and $\odot$ denotes Hadamard product.

We would like to know if there exists an $\boldsymbol{X}$, given the previous restrictions (i.e., full-rank and at least one non-zero element per column, and last $(m-r)$ columns linearly independent), for having
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{rank}\left( (\boldsymbol{X}^H\boldsymbol{X} \otimes \boldsymbol{1}_{l\times l}) \odot \boldsymbol{H}^H\boldsymbol{H} \right) < m\cdot l.
\end{equation}

In case there's no $\boldsymbol{X}$ fulfilling this, how would it be proved?